# return value is not displayed if printf in the other method is commented

Tags: c

It seems that something weird is happening in my code below. When any of the printf in the nthtoken() is commented, no token is displayed in main(), but when any of the nthtoken()'s printf is uncommented, token is displayed in main.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>

 char *nthtoken (char *origStr, char *delimiters, int nth);

 int main (void) {

      char *str = "in principio creavit deus caelum et terram";
      char *delims = " ";

      char *tok = nthtoken (str, delims, 3);
      printf ("token: %s\n", tok);

      return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
 }

 char *nthtoken (char *origStr, char *delimiters, int nth) {

      char str[strlen (origStr)];
      strncpy (str, origStr, strlen (origStr) + 1);

      char *token = NULL;
      token = strtok (str, delimiters);
      // printf ("first token: %s\n", token);

      int i = 0;
      for (i = 0; i < nth; i++) {
           token = strtok (NULL, delimiters);
           //printf ("token inside the loop: %s\n", token); 
      }
      // printf ("token before returning to main(): %s\n", token);
      return token;
 }
```

Comment: You're returning a pointer to a local variable...

Comment: how should i modify the program?

Comment: @chrismsawi i have added one possible way to do it in code. But make sure you understand the concept

Comment: You've got a buffer overflow in `nthtoken()`; you allocate space for `strlen(origStr)` characters, and promptly copy `strlen(origStr)+1` characters into the space.  *BAD!*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic mistake. token is local. Returning it would produce unpredictable result. You might get it in printf, if it hasn't been over written, but it is not guaranteed and you should not do it. Bottom line is that upon function termination local variables are out of scope and technically no longer exist to compiler or run time.

Either malloc and copy the token to it (and free it in main) or pass it to the function as an out parameter, for instance

```
char * ret_string = malloc(MAX_SIZE); // ensure this is always sufficiently large
strcpy(ret_string, token);
return ret_string;
```

Don'f forget to free the malloc memory in main.

Edit: **Thread safety note** - As @grhegde suggested, Just for the record, strtok is not thread safe.If you are in a multithreaded environment, then you better find an alternative.

To further explain this, strtok uses a global buffer to keep track of tokens, this means that it cannot be called for tokenizing another string *while one string is being tokenized*
A standard solution to do this is often given with a function called strtok_r (r for re-entrant) where the implementation uses a local buffer for each call and hence can be called easily from multiple threads.

Comment: @grhegde i was editing my own answer and your suggestion was rejected in the middle. It was a valuable point to add so i manually added it latter with your name along with some more explanation

Comment: i see. i'll change my implementation, since there's a possibility that the above code will be use in a multithreaded environment. thanks! :)

Comment: Note that `strtok()` is not only not thread safe, it is also not safe in a single-threaded program. If a function `f` uses `strtok()`, then (a) `f` must not call any other function that also uses `strtok()`, because that other function will modify the storage that `f` was using, and (b) no function that calls `f` can afford to be using `strtok()` at the time because `f` will modify the storage that the calling function was using. A function that uses `strtok()` is essentially unreusable — it cannot safely be put into a library. Or, if put into a library, it must carry prominent warning flags.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using malloc and taking overhead of free you can work this way also...

```
#include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>

 char *nthtoken (char *str, char *delimiters, int nth);

 int main (void) {

      char str[] = "in principio creavit deus caelum et terram";
      char *delims = " ";

      char *tok = nthtoken (str, delims, 3);
      printf ("token: %s\n", tok);

      return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
 }

 char *nthtoken (char *str, char *delimiters, int nth) {

      char *token = NULL;
      token = strtok (str, delimiters);
      // printf ("first token: %s\n", token);

      int i = 0;
      for (i = 0; i < nth; i++) {
                token = strtok (NULL, delimiters);
               //printf ("token inside the loop: %s\n", token); 
      }
      // printf ("token before returning to main(): %s\n", token);
       return token;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called **dangling pointer** issue.

```
{
  char *token = NULL;
  ....

  return token;
}
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer